Gnuplot can't find {/Symbol } fonts with png/jpeg/gif terminals for gnuplot 6.0 on Ubuntu 24.04.1
gnuplot> set xlabel "{/Symbol t}"
gnuplot> set term png; set out "test.png"; plot x;set out

Terminal type is now 'png'
Options are 'truecolor nocrop enhanced butt size 640,480 font "arial,12.0" '
gdImageStringFT: fontconfig: Didn't find expected font family. Perhaps URW Type 1 fonts need installing? while printing string t with font Symbol
gdImageStringFT: fontconfig: Didn't find expected font family. Perhaps URW Type 1 fonts need installing? while printing string t with font Symbol

The xlabel is blank
Similar error message for the jpeg and gif terminals. The PDF terminal works fine, and τ is printed fine.
packages installed: gnuplot-qt/noble,now 6.0.0+dfsg1-1ubuntu3 amd64
fonts-urw-base35/noble,noble,now 20200910-8 all
gnuplot 6.0 patchlevel 0
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 6.8.0-47-generic
DE: GNOME 46.0

It looks like the fonts-urw-base35 package doesn't provide a Symbol fontfile - however it does provide StandardSymbolsPS, and set xlabel "{/StandardSymbolsPS t}" appears to work for me. Perhaps there's a way to map that to Symbol via fontconfig? Or even a symlink?

steeldriver provides a solution that works from me as well. Use set xlabel "{/StandardSymbolsPS t}" instead of set xlabel "{/Symbols t}"
Of course the problem remains in all of my old scripts that use Symbol, and may have portability problems if StandardSymbolsPS is not available. Maybe the font should be provided in Ubuntu in some way in a future update.
